# How do FTP servers handle renaming an existing file name?

Tags: ftp

How do FTP servers normally handle renaming to a file name that already exists? That is, will the existing to-file be overwritten or will I get an error? Is there some specification about how FTP servers should handle this, or is it OS or implementation dependent?

vsftpd on Linux seems to overwrite, with FileZilla on Vista I get 550 file exists...

Comment: You probably shouldn't cross-post the same question to both SF and SU like that (http://superuser.com/questions/38912/how-does-ftp-servers-handle-rename-to-existing-file/).

Comment: Agreed, but I'm not sure where the question belongs. Was trying to figure out where it's best to post it, but posted on both to see where I got the best answers...

Comment: Not sure why you're asking, since you already tried it.  I've never used and ftpd that did anything other than overwrite in that situation though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 959 doesn't say anything about this, so I can assume it's implementation-dependent.